# RadioButton positioning on Form

Tags: c#

I am trying to dynamically add radiobuttons to a form (so I can change their values when the user clicks a button) but then I added Location information for the individual buttons they no longer appear at all. I can see the outline of the GroupBox on the form, as well as several hundred pixels on every side.

```
private void AddQ1()
{
   questionBox = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
   questionBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1200, 250);
   questionBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 700);
   questionBox.Text = "To What extent is this person... striking a pose?";

   RadioButton radioButton1;
   for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)//opt 1,2,3,4,5
   {
       radioButton1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
       radioButton1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
       radioButton1.Tag = i.ToString();
       radioButton1.Text = i.ToString();
       radioButton1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1200, (250+(10*i)));
       questionBox.Controls.Add(radioButton1);
       rbList.Add(radioButton1);
   }
   Controls.Add(questionBox);
}
```

Comment: Use a table layout label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Location is the Point that represents the upper-left corner of the control **relative** to the upper-left corner of its container.
try

```
radioButton1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, (250+(10*i)));
```

Answer (score 0):

The location of the radio buttons will not be visible in your code above. 
The location property is relational with the container

see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location%28v=vs.110%29.aspx